# Shell scripting UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

we have a file containing list of few elements, each element has to be checked for its presence in a directory containing multiple folders and sub folders and files.
if we find particlar element we should populate it one file and if it is not present it has to be populated into other file... How we do it with unix shell scripting? 
Example: file1:
               A
           B
           C
               D
if we find elemnt A/B/C/D in any file it should be populated in one file named "present.txt" else in "Absent.txt". 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You did not make it clear if there was one filename per line in the elements file, or several on each line.  My test input file, gash.txt, had the following:

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
```

If one per line then the script would be simpler.  Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Initialise filenames
elements=gash.txt
directory=gash
present=present.txt
absent=absent.txt

# Note that when these are used I enclose them in "quotes"
# This is to guard against embedded spaces in the names

# Zeroise files
> "$present"
> "$absent"

# If you have command-line arguments then save them here
# because I am about to blow them away with the 'set'

# 'read' reads each line into variable 'REPLY' by default
while read 
do
    # This 'set' trick will overwrite the program parameters
    # It will NOT work if the names in $elements have embedded whitespace
    set $REPLY

    # This loops through the command-line arguments by default
    for fname
    do 
        # if you don't know the 'find' command then look at 'man find'
        # Note that 'find' returns 0 even if it didn't find the file
        result=$(find "$directory" -name "$fname")

        # The '-n' test returns true if $result is not empty
        if [[ -n $result ]]
        then
            echo "$fname found"
            echo "$fname" >> "$present"
        else
            echo "$fname not found"
            echo "$fname" >> "$absent"
        fi

    done

done < "$elements"
```

A more sophisticated version would construct a pattern from the filenames and do the search using just one call to 'find', but life is too short for that (maybe a good project for later).

Answer (score 0):

You may also do that :

file1 contains :

```
A
B
C
D
```

code :

```
directory="your path"

cat file1 | while read line
do
     res=$(find $directory -name "$line")
     if [[ -n $res ]]
     then
         echo $line >> present.txt
     else
         echo $line >> absent.txt
     fi
done
```

Best regards